# Transferring file in client-server program but all bytes not being transmitted

Tags: java, client-server

I am currently writing a client-server program that would allow me to upload a file from the client to the server. However, when I try this the file becomes corrupt and it appears not all the bytes are being transferred. Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks.

Here is part of the client code:

```
System.out.println("What file would you like to upload?");
String file=in.next();//get file name
outToServer.writeUTF(file);//send file name to server
File test= new File(file);//create file

byte[] bits = new byte[(int) test.length()]; //byte array to store file
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(test); //read in file

//write bytes into array
int size=(int) test.length();//size of array
outToServer.write(size);//send size of array to Server

fis.read(bits);//read in byte values
fis.close();//close stream
outToServer.write(bits, 0, size);//writes bytes out to server
```

And here is the server code:

```
String filename= inFromClient.readUTF();//read in file name that is being uploaded

int size=inFromClient.read(); //read in size of file
byte[] bots=new byte[size]; //create array
inFromClient.read(bots);  //read in bytes

FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(filename);
fos.write(bots);
fos.flush();
fos.close();

String complete="Upload Complete.";
outToClient.writeUTF(complete);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use Java 7's `Files.copy()`.

On the client side:

```
final Path source = Paths.get(file);
Files.copy(source, outToServer);
```

On the server side:

```
final Path destination = Paths.get(file);
Files.copy(inFromClient, destination);
```

See the [javadoc for `Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: thanks for your input. I tried your code, but there is a file already exists exception. anyway to get around this?

Comment: If you want to overwrite the file each time, on the server side, use `Files.copy(inFromClient, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)`

Comment: so now there is an access denied exception.

Comment: Hehe, meaningful exceptions are great, aren't they? ;) It means what it means: you don't have the necessary permissions to write to this file. Choose a directory you can write to!

Comment: agreed. thanks for introducing me to the Files class. but now it seems to be denying access to all files i try to access. is it an admin issue?

Comment: All files?? Even those under your homedir? That seems weird

Comment: yea, not sure whats going on.

Comment: OS is a windows 8. just got it.

Comment: sorry. just got as in, i just got the os last week.

Comment: Try and create a directory under `System.getProperty("user.home")`; ie: `final Path baseDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "uploads");` -- then create all files relative to that directory: `final Path destination = baseDir.resolve(filename);`

Comment: Glad that you worked it out! And welcome to the wonderful world of Java 7's file API ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usual mistake. You're assuming that read() fills the buffer. It isn't obliged to do that. See the Javadoc.

The canonical way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this at both ends. You don't need a buffer the size of the file either. This works for any byte array with one or more elements.

Comment: i tried your solution, but it's giving me an Arrayoutofbounds exception...so I'm assuming the value of the file length is smaller than the count. any ways around this?